# D3 lines and scope

Tags: d3.js

I am having some issues with D3 regarding the scope of a variable.

I am trying to draw two lines that represent the limits of integration of a function. I have my two lines but I am having problems restricting the x values they can assume.

I have restricted both lines to only exist when my function is nonzero and positive but line A can only assume values below or equal to line B and line B should only assume values greater than or equal to line A.

Here is my code for line A. The code for line B is similar and in the same function:

```
function initDragLines () {
    var svg = d3.select("#svg");
    var lineA = svg.append("line");
    var min_x = 45;
    var max_x = 455;

    var dragA = d3.behavior.drag()
        .on('dragstart', null)
        .on('drag', function(d) {
            var dx = d3.event.x;
            var x1a = dx > max_x ? max_x : dx < min_x ? min_x : dx;
            //Should be something like x1b = dx > x1b ? x1b : dx < min_x ? min_x : dx;

            lineA.attr("x1", x1a)
                .attr("x2", x1a);

        })
        .on('dragend', function() {});

    lineA.attr("x1", 45) 
        .attr("y1", 143)
        .attr("x2", 45)
        .attr("y2", 370)
        .attr("stroke-width", 5)
        .attr("stroke", "black")
        .call(dragA);
}
```

The problem arises when I try to pass the value of either x1a or x1b into the other line because they can't see each other. I'm not even sure if I /can/ pass values such as x1a or x1b.

I have tried to mess around with function(d) and return statements but nothing in that sort has worked for me either. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks guys.

Edit: Removed some auxiliary code unrelated to the functionality.

Comment: Can you edit the code you posted to include somewhere you tried to pass `x1a` or `x1b` into the other line?

Comment: An [MCVE] would help. Is this the minimal set of code to illustrate the problem?

Comment: @SimonBilsky-Rollins I've tried directly putting x1a into the x1b line at first. Then I tried using return statements, making two functions, using "d." I don't have that portion of the code edited anymore because it did not work.

Comment: @Anko I have removed some of the code that was irrelevant to the reader. Thanks! This is now the minimal set of code assuming that the code for line B is the same except for changed names.

Comment: @allegro even though it did not work, it would really help to see that code so that it is more clear exactly what you are trying to do and how your current approach is failing. This would satisfy the "complete" part of a minimal, complete, and verifiable example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys, complete forgot about this post and I just figured out how to do it.
The problem was fixed by introducing x1aPass, x1bPass and the dummy variables.

The code is below:

```
function dragLineA (dummyA) {

var dragA = d3.behavior.drag()

.on('dragstart', null)
.on('drag', function(d) {
    var dx = d3.event.x;
    var x1a = dx > x1bPass ? x1bPass  : dx < min_x ? min_x : dx;
    x1aPass = x1a;

    lineA.attr("x1", x1a).attr("x2", x1a)  

 }).on('dragend', function() {});

lineA.attr("x1", 45).attr("y1", 145).attr("x2", 45).attr("y2", 370).attr("stroke-width", 5).attr("stroke", "black").call(dragA);

lineA.on({
  "mouseover": function(d) {
    d3.select(this).style("cursor", "ew-resize"); 
  },
})  
}

function dragLineB (dummyB) {

var dragB = d3.behavior.drag()
.on('dragstart', null)
.on('drag', function(d) {
var dx = d3.event.x;
var x1b = dx > max_x ? max_x : dx < x1aPass ? x1aPass : dx;
    x1bPass = x1b;

lineB.attr("x1", x1b).attr("x2", x1b);

}).on('dragend', function() {});

lineB.attr("x1", 455).attr("y1", 145).attr("x2", 455).attr("y2", 370).attr("stroke-width", 5).attr("stroke", "blue").call(dragB);

 lineB.on({
  "mouseover": function(d) {
    d3.select(this).style("cursor", "ew-resize"); 
  },
});
```

}